# How To Get Value by using Column number from mysql database using php

Tags: php

I want to get the value of Column using numbers 
is it possible in php to get the $row value by column number

I Want to run foeach loop for column and get value by column number

```
try {
    $database =  new DB();
    $db = $database->Connect();

    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        $data .='<tr>';
        $columnNumber = 0;

        foreach ($db->query($sql) as $column)
        {
            $data .= "<td>";
            $data .= $row[$columnNumber];
            $data .= "</td>";
        }
        $data .='</tr>';

    }
    $database->Close();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $data .= "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Define columns in an array and access it over numeric index: `$columns = ['col1', 'col2', ...]; $row[$columns[colNumber]]`;

Comment: Or start using associative results, and have clear code.

Comment: Can you write it down i did not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you simply want your code to work, you could do:

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $data .='<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $column)
    {
        $data .= "<td>";
        $data .= $column;
        $data .= "</td>";
    }
    $data .='</tr>';
}
```

Or if you really need to know the 'number' of the column, you could do:

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $data .='<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $columnNumber => $column)
    {
        $data .= "<td>";
        $data .= $row[$columnNumber];
        $data .= "</td>";
    }
    $data .='</tr>';
}
```